# output of k-mean cluster as collection of tweets

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining, k-means

I want to cluster some 1000 tweets using k-mean algorithm. But I don't want the correct output, I just want clustering of tweets.

Suppose 1 cluster contain 300 tweets than all the contain of 300 tweets (contain consist main words of tweet after preprocessing of tweets) in form of text as my output. I don't want top term of cluster but all the terms in cluster. Here in R I implement k-mean.

```
tweets_dtm <-DocumentTermMatrix(clean_corp,control=dtm.control)
dtm <- weightTfIdf(tweets_dtm, normalize = TRUE)
m  <- as.matrix(dtm)
rownames(m)<-1:nrow(m)
norm_eucl<-function(m)
  m/apply(m,1,function(x) sum(x^2)^0.5)
m_form<-norm_eucl(m)
result<-kmeans(m_form,5,5)

for(i in 1:5)
{

  cat("cluster",i,":",findFreqTerms(dtm[result$cluster],2),"\n\n");

}
```

At the end I get error in below code.

```
cat("cluster",i,":",findFreqTerms(dtm[result$cluster],2),"\n\n"); 

Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors.
```

Please suggest any other way to just cluster the tweets and the output like 1 cluster contain all text terms of clustered tweets.